# why do I get undefined variable error while trying to access a global vairable from a function?

Tags: php

I've written a code like following in php

```
<?php

  global $server ,$username ,$password ,$database; 
  $server ="localhost:3306";
  $username="user";
  $password="pass";
  $database="dbname";

  function connectToDB()
  {
     mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die ("can't connect to server");
     mysql_select_db($database) or die ("can't select database");
  }
?>
```

but I'm not able to access those variables inside my function what is my problem?

even without the global keyword I'm not able to access those variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`global` means "Get this variable from the global scope" not "Make this variable available in all functions". You use it inside functions, not outside them.

See the [example in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

```
<?php

  $server ="localhost:3306";
  $username="user";
  $password="pass";
  $database="dbname";

  function connectToDB()
  {
     // Global used INSIDE function
     global $server ,$username ,$password ,$database; 
     mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die ("can't connect to server");
     mysql_select_db($database) or die ("can't select database");
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the variables [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) INSIDE the function:

```
function connectToDB() {
    global $server, $username, $password, $database;
    etc...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not good practice to use global variables as they can be modified in unexpected places creating hard to track bugs. A better way is to pass the variables you need into your function like this:-

```
$server ="localhost:3306";
$username="user";
$password="pass";
$database="dbname";

connectToDB($server, $username, $password, $database);

function connectToDB($server, $username, $password, $database)
{
    mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password) or die ("can't connect to server");
    mysqli_select_db($database) or die ("can't select database");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function connectToDB()
  {
     global $server ,$username ,$password ,$database; 

     $server ="localhost:3306";
     $username="user";
     $password="pass";
     $database="dbname";

     mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die ("can't connect to server");
     mysql_select_db($database) or die ("can't select database");
  }
?>
```